# How to render HTML element only if it's content is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to insert an HTML element in the page only if there is text to put into it?

For example, in the below snippet, I would like that the second `<li></li>` is not added to the page if somedata is blank or nil:

```
<ul>
  <li>item</item>
  - magic_method(somedata) do |somedata|
    <li>
      <%= somedata %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a built-in method in Rails (or HAML or ERB) for this?

UPDATE:

PS. I am aware of various other methods of doing this on my own; my question is specifically targeted at whether there is a Rails built-in way to do the above.

Comment: I am sure you should take a look at frameworks like Vue, React which operate with DOM and allow you to archieve your goal

Comment: `<% if somedata.present? %>`
  your content `<% end %>`

Comment: I would say my answer (similar to @bhanu comment) is the built in Rails/ERB way to do this.  Your template demonstrating your desired syntax won't work, and there is nothing in Rails that would make it work.  Any ruby code would need to be wrapped in ERB tags like `<% magic_method(somedata) do |somedata| %>` and would need a `<% end %>` tag to close the block.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are running into in which the standard approach is not working for you?  Could you share a more detailed use case demonstrating your issue if this is the case?

Comment: No a specific problem @DRSE, just trying to make the template look a bit nicer

Answer (score -1):

The standard way to do this in Rails is to evaluate a conditional in your ERB template.

```
<ul>
  <li>item</item>
  <% if somedata.present? %>
    <li>
      <%= somedata %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The code between the `<% if %> . . . <% end %>` will only be evaluated and output if the conditional evaluates to `true` (or [truthy](https://learn.co/lessons/truthiness-in-ruby-readme)). Please see the [Rails doc for the `#present?` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) and how it works.  It may be a good fit depending on what type of object you are expecting for `somedata`.